# Searchable Dropdown value in Dynamically added rows

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-select2

Im using php and simple js to add searchable dropdown list in Dynamically added rows, My problem is that, When i add the first rows, the searchable dropdown works fine, but when i add another row, dropdown does not work... Can anyone help me solving this
 [image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('click','.btn_addOrder', function(){
        var html='';
        html+='<tr>';
        html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control productname" style="display:none" name="productname[]" readonly></td>';
        html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control totalcp" style="display:none" name="totalcp[]" readonly></td>';
        html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control unitcode" style="display:none" name="unitcode[]" readonly></td>';
        html+='<td><input type="hidden" class="form-control productcode" name="productcode[]" readonly></td>';
        html+='<td><select class="form-control productid" name="productid[]" id="productid"  required><option value="0">--Select Product--</option></select></td>';        
        html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control productstock" name="productstock[]" readonly></td>';
        html+='<td><input type="number"  class="form-control quantity_product" name="quantity[]" required></td>';
        html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control productsatuan"  name="productsatuan[]" readonly></td>';
        html+='<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-remove"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button></td>';

        $('#myStock').append(html);
        $("#productid").select2({
        ajax:{
          url:"prod.php",
          type:"post",
          dataType:"json",
          delay:250,
          data:function(params){     return{   searchTerm:params.term        };      },
          processResults:function(response){   return{       results:response          };    },
          cache:true
          }
        });

        $('.productid').on('change', function(e){
          var productid = this.value;
          var tr=$(this).parent().parent();
          $.ajax({
            url:"getproduct.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{id:productid},
            success:function(data){
              //console.log(data);
              tr.find(".productcode").val(data["product_code"]);
              tr.find(".productname").val(data["product_name"]);
              tr.find(".productstock").val(data["stock"]);
              tr.find(".productsatuan").val(data["nm_satuan"]);
              tr.find(".unitcode").val(data["kd_satuan"]);
              tr.find(".totalcp").val(data["total_cp"]);
              tr.find(".quantity_product").val(0);
             }
          })
        })
      })
      //Remove Row
      $(document).on('click','.btn-remove', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in that you use an **id** to initialize and select your select2 searchable dropdown and ids should be unique, so it is used only once.

An easy way to fix this without updating your code much would be to add an index and increment it every time you click the `btn_addOrder` button. Then you can attach this index to your selector and it will work.

Your code then would look like the following:

```
let i=0;
$(document).on('click','.btn_addOrder', function(){
    var html='';
    html+='<tr>';
    html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control productname" style="display:none" name="productname[]" readonly></td>';
    html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control totalcp" style="display:none" name="totalcp[]" readonly></td>';
    html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control unitcode" style="display:none" name="unitcode[]" readonly></td>';
    html+='<td><input type="hidden" class="form-control productcode" name="productcode[]" readonly></td>';
    html+='<td><select class="form-control productid" name="productid[]" id="productid'+i+'"  required><option value="0">--Select Product--</option></select></td>';
    html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control productstock" name="productstock[]" readonly></td>';
    html+='<td><input type="number"  class="form-control quantity_product" name="quantity[]" required></td>';
    html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control productsatuan"  name="productsatuan[]" readonly></td>';
    html+='<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-remove"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button></td>';

    $('#myStock').append(html);

    $("#productid"+i).select2({
        ajax:{
            url:"prod.php",
            type:"post",
            dataType:"json",
            delay:250,
            data:function(params){     return{   searchTerm:params.term        };      },
            processResults:function(response){   return{       results:response          };    },
            cache:true
            }
        });
    i++;
});
```

So first I define a variable `i=0;`

Then on the html line where you append the dropdown I edit the id to `id="productid'+i+'"`.

I rename the selector to `$("#productid"+i).select2({` to select the right item.

Finally I add the `i++;` at the end of the `btn_addOrder` function to make sure that the `i` auto increments every time you click the button.